# how to have no enclosing tags with React?

Tags: reactjs

I want a component to return sibling tags instead of a single parent tag. For example render method of `DefaultItems` should return something that renders as `<li/><li/>` instead of say, `<div><li/><li/></div>`. But React **needs enclosing tag** when returning something.

Is there some null tag which does not insert into the final markup?

JSX:

```
<ul>
<DefaultItems/>
<OtherItems/>
<li>
```

Desired:

```
<ul>
<li>default 1</li>
<li>default 2</li>
<li>other 1</li>
<li>
```

The best I can do, notice the unwanted div around the li:

```
<ul>
<div>
<li>default 1</li>
<li>default 2</li>
</div>
<li>other 1</li>
<li>
```

I wish a "null tag" exists:

```
return <nulltag>
<li>default 1</li>
<li>default 2</li>
</nulltag>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  You may need to elaborate.  Do you mean you're trying to conditionally render the DefaultItems component or that you're trying to replace the DefaultItems content, similar to Angular's ng-transclude?

Comment: @sma  I have edited the question. Its just about the enclosing tags. I never learned Angular.

Comment: You can return an array of elements instead in your render statement if you want.  But you need to give them keys.  So your `<DefaultItems />` and etc could just return an array of `<li key={something}>foo</li>` and then you wouldn't get an enclosing `<div />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A react components, render function must return a single element.

This 1 to 1 relationship makes components much easier to reason about.
What it means for us developers is that we have to divide our apps into components that follow this rule.
Rather than having a component that returns two li elements, you must return one. This is a good thing. It makes your components much more reusable. 
A common pattern is to have one component that represents a list (of something), and a different component that represents the items in the list.

instead of:

```
...
<ul>
 <ItemList items={list}/>
</ul>
...
```

you have:

```
...
<ItemList items={list}/>
...
```

you can still create a list of different items

```
...
makeList(items) {
  return items.map(function (item) {
    // return what ever component you want based on the item
  });
},
render () {
  return (
    <ul>
     {makeList(this.props.items)}
    </ul>
  );
},
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work with arrays in React, but maybe you should reconsider the logic behind creating the list items.

Instead of having separate components for different data types, you can have a factory for creating arrays of list items inside the render method that passes the item data, f.ex something like this:

```
var i = 0   

var listFactory = function(item) {
    return <ListItem item={item} key={i++} />
}

var DefaultItems = defaultData.map(listFactory)
var OtherItems = otherData.map(listFactory)

<ul>
  <DefaultItems />
  <OtherItems />
</ul>
```

IMO, having a single component for a certain type (`ListItem`) is preferred over having separate components for different content or data.